# discord.js bot reply if user has a specific role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need my bot to reply to a specific role and if the user dont have the role the bot replies back with another message says "u are not allowed to perform this command" here is my code :

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    // Command handler, seen previously
    if (message.content === "#سرقة") {
        let frole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("861336755197575178");

        if (frole) return message.channel.send("u are not allowed to use this command");

        message.reply("يرجى تحديد نوع السرقة");
        message.channel.send(" -بقالة");
        message.channel.send("-محل ملابس");
        message.channel.send("-البنك المركزي");
    }
});
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Have you tried looking up ways to check if a member has a certain role?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GuildMemberRoleManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache).[`has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has) to determine if a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) has a [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role).

---

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "#سرقة") {
        if (message.member.roles.cache.has("861336755197575178")) {
            message.reply("You are allowed to use this command.");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You are not allowed to use this command.");
        }
    }
});
```